# What's the bibliographstyle of this Bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

[image]

Is there an appropriate style file for this kind of Bibliography?

Comment: Such a style is easy to produce in `biblatex`.

Comment: I am not quite familiar with latex. How can we write a bibliography of our own style?@DavidPurton

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shown snippet is by far not enough to build a complete `biblatex` style. Too many details are missing, in particular the very important formatting of `@article` entries.

Using `biblatex-ext` (for `pubinstorg+location+date`) you can build something like

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ext-numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibbold{\mkbibemph{#1}}}

\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \setunit*{\publocdelim}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\locdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{nussbaum,cicero,worman,companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Nancy Worman. The Cast of Character. Style in Greek Literature. University of Texas Press, Austin, 2002.]

More general hints to get started can be found in [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864). If you have more questions, I strongly suggest to isolate concrete questions like 'How can I get the title of books in bold italics?' or 'How can I change the order of "location: publisher, date" to "publisher, location, date"' and include an example document (a so-called MWE [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), [How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)) of what you have so far.