# Changing part of a style in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, overleaf, bibliographystyle

I'm new to `biblatex` and I want to set up my bibliography. I have searched and found a style that is almost correct.

Is there an easy way to change part of the style in Overleaf?

Below there is a picture of the things I want to change for @Incollection, @Inbook, @Book, and @Article.

[image]

Lastly, I have an MWE producing the bibliography and a manual version of how I want it to look.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
oneside,
,
12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=nature,
sorting=none,
maxbibnames=99
]{biblatex}

´´´
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
    @incollection{InCol,
        author = {Hrdy, Sarah Blaffer},
        year = {2007},
        pages = {39--68},
        title = {Evolutionary Context of Human Development: The Cooperative Breeding Model},
        publisher ={Oxford University Press, Oxford},
        booktitle = {Family Relationships: An Evolutionary Perspective},
        editor={Salmon, Catherine A and Todd K. Shackelford}
    }
    
    
    @inbook{inBook,
        author = {Creel, S and Creel, N.M},
        chapter = {Demography — Survival and Reproduction},
        title = {The African Wild Dog: Behavior, Ecology, and Conservation},
        year = {2019},
        publisher = {Princeton University Press, New Jersey},
        pages = {145--178}
    }
    
    
    @book{Book,
        author = {Estes, Richard},
        year = {1991},
        title = {The behavior guide to African mammals : including hoofed mammals, carnivores, primates},
        publisher = {University of California Press, Berkeley},
        pages = {134}
    }
    
    
    @article{Article,
        title = {Relatedness and conflict over optimal group size},
        journal = {Trends in Ecology $\&$ Evolution},
        volume = {9},
        number = {4},
        pages = {117--119},
        year = {1994},
        author = {Bruce H. Rannala and Charles R. Brown}
    }
\end{filecontents}



\addbibresource{biblio.bib}



\begin{document}
    
    Four types of citations which needs to be altered:
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Incollection: \cite{InCol}
        \item Inbook: \cite{inBook}
        \item Book: \cite{Book}
        \item Article : \cite{Article}
    \end{enumerate}
    
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
    
    
    
    \textbf{How i want it to look}
    
    
    \begin{enumerate}[1.  ]
        \item
        Hrdy, S. B. Evolutionary Context of Human Development: The Cooperative Breeding Model. In: Salmon, C. A. $\&$ Shackelford, T. K. (eds.), \emph{Family Relationships: An Evolutionary Perspective}, pp. 39--68. Oxford University Press, Oxford, 2007 
        \item
        Creel,  S.  $\&$  Creel,  N. Demography -- Survival and Reproduction. In: \emph{The African Wild Dog: Behavior, Ecology, and Conservation}, pp. 145--178. Princeton  University  Press,  New Jersey, 2019
        \item
        Estes,  R. \emph{The behavior guide to African mammals: including hoofed mammals, carnivores, primates}, pp. 134. University  of  California  Press, Berkeley, 1991
        \item 
        Rannala, B. H. $\&$ Brown, C. R. Relatedness and conflict over optimal group size. \emph{Trends in Ecology $\&$ Evolution} \textbf{9}: 117--119, 1994
    \end{enumerate}
    
    
    
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no pre-made style for what you need, I suggest you start with one of the standard styles (or one of the styles from my `biblatex-ext` bundle) and not from a customised third-party style. The standard and `biblatex-ext` styles are intended for customisation, whereas many contributed styles are not.

Some of the easier modifications below are discussed in [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864). Some specifics are from [Move names of editors followed by (Ed./Eds.) and a comma before title in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173638/35864), [What's the bibliographstyle of this Bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/476437/35864). The other things should hopefully become clear from the names of the macros involved. Additional hints can be found in the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) and the [`biblatex-ext` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf).

If there are any questions you have about the code that you could not answer with the linked resources, please ask away in the comments.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-numeric,
  sorting=none,
  maxbibnames=99,
  giveninits=true,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  articlein=false,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{innametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuedate}{#1}


\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{}
\newcommand*{\artbibpagespunct}{\addcolon\space}
\newcommand*{\artbibeidpunct}{\artbibpagespunct}
\newcommand*{\pagedatedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\jourvoldelim}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\jourserdelim}%
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\servoldelim}}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\volnumdelim}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\artbibeidpunct}%
  \printfield{eid}%
  \setunit{\artbibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \clearfield{pages}%
  \setunit{\pagedatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{edition}{%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \clearfield{pages}%
  \setunit{\bibeidpunct}%
  \printfield{eid}%
  \clearfield{eid}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \setunit*{\publocdelim}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\locdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{InCol,
  author       = {Hrdy, Sarah Blaffer},
  year         = {2007},
  pages        = {39--68},
  title        = {Evolutionary Context of Human Development},
  subtitle     = {The Cooperative Breeding Model},
  publisher    = {Oxford University Press},
  location     = {Oxford},
  booktitle    = {Family Relationships},
  booksubtitle = {An Evolutionary Perspective},
  editor       = {Salmon, Catherine A. and Todd K. Shackelford}
}
@inbook{inBook,
  author       = {Creel, S. and Creel, N. M.},
  title        = {Demography -- Survival and Reproduction},
  booktitle    = {The {African} Wild Dog},
  booksubtitle = {Behavior, Ecology, and Conservation},
  year         = {2019},
  publisher    = {Princeton University Press},
  location     = {New Jersey},
  pages        = {145--178}
}
@book{Book,
  author    = {Estes, Richard},
  year      = {1991},
  title     = {The Behavior Guide to {African} Mammals},
  subtitle  = {Including Hoofed Mammals, Carnivores, Primates},
  publisher = {University of California Press},
  location  = {Berkeley},
  pages     = {134}
}
@article{Article,
  title   = {Relatedness and Conflict Over Optimal Group Size},
  journal = {Trends in Ecology \& Evolution},
  volume  = {9},
  number  = {4},
  pages   = {117--119},
  year    = {1994},
  author  = {Bruce H. Rannala and Charles R. Brown}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Four types of citations which needs to be altered:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Incollection: \cite{InCol}
    \item Inbook: \cite{inBook}
    \item Book: \cite{Book}
    \item Article : \cite{Article}
\end{enumerate}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\textbf{How I want it to look}
\begin{enumerate}[1.]
  \item
  Hrdy, S. B. Evolutionary Context of Human Development: The Cooperative Breeding Model.
  In: Salmon, C. A. $\&$ Shackelford, T. K. (eds.),
  \emph{Family Relationships: An Evolutionary Perspective}, pp. 39--68.
  Oxford University Press, Oxford, 2007
  \item
  Creel,  S.  $\&$  Creel,  N. Demography -- Survival and Reproduction.
  In: \emph{The African Wild Dog: Behavior, Ecology, and Conservation}, pp. 145--178.
  Princeton  University  Press,  New Jersey, 2019
  \item
  Estes,  R. \emph{The behavior guide to African mammals:
    including hoofed mammals, carnivores, primates}, pp. 134.
  University  of  California  Press, Berkeley, 1991
  \item
  Rannala, B. H. $\&$ Brown, C. R. Relatedness and conflict over optimal group size.
  \emph{Trends in Ecology $\&$ Evolution} \textbf{9}: 117--119, 1994
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: Hrdy, S. B. Evolutionary Context of Human Development. The Cooperative Breeding Model. In: C. A. Salmon & T. K. Shackelford (eds.), Family Relationships. An Evolutionary Perspective, pp. 39–68. Oxford University Press, Oxford, 2007. Creel, S. & Creel, N. M. Demography – Survival and Reproduction. In: The African Wild Dog. Behavior, Ecology, and Conservation, pp. 145–178. Princeton University Press, New Jersey, 2019. Estes, R. The Behavior Guide to African Mammals. Including Hoofed Mammals, Carnivores, Primates, p. 134. University of California Press, Berkeley, 1991. Rannala, B. H. & Brown, C. R. Relatedness and Conflict Over Optimal Group Size. Trends in Ecology & Evolution 9(4): 117–119, 1994.]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help - it solves all of my problems ! Furthermore your code is easy to read and I learnt something today!